# django html template can't find static css and js files

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a django project that structure is like this:

```
>vira
     >vira
          -__init.py
          -settings.py
          -urls.py
          -wsgi.py
     >vira_app
          >migrations
          >template
                  -index.html
                  >static
                        >vira_app
                                >assets
                                      >css
                                      >js
                                      >vendor
                                          >aos
                                          >bootstrap
                                          >bootstrap-icons
                                          >isotope-layout
                                          >swiper
          -__init__.py
          -admin.py
          -apps.py
          -models.py
          -tests.py
          -urls.py
          -views.py
     -db.sqlite3
     -manage.py
```

I have used bootstrap. index.html is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  {% load static %}
  <link href="{% static 'vira_app/assets/vendor/aos/aos.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'vira_app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'vira_app/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'vira_app/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  {% load static %}
  <link href="{% static 'vira_app/assets/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
        <div id="portfolio-grid" class="row no-gutter" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
          {% if catalogue_list %}
            {% for Catalogue in catalogue_list %}
              <div class="item web col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                <a href="{{ Catalogue.link }}" class="item-wrap fancybox">
                  <div class="work-info">
                    <h3>{{ Catalogue.title }}</h3>
                    <span>{{ Catalogue.source }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ Catalogue.image }}">
                </a>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
  <a href="#" class="back-to-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>
  <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vira_app', 'template')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vira_app/template'
```

When I run the server and go to index.html, data retrieved from db and show well, but without any style!

I have tried some solution, check every static url, but not working

In fact, css, js and vendors not applied. What's the problem?

Comment: have you configured STATIC_URL or STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/ read this

Comment: @Sumithran I have both STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT, but still not working

Comment: Please grab any of static urls from the rendered page and open it in a separate tab. Add the response status / error message you get to the question.

Comment: I think your static folder needs to be in the same directory as the templates folder, not inside of it

Comment: @Serket Still not working

Comment: Give this a try ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

Comment: @Sumithran It worked! style is ok, but everything is hidden!

Comment: what you mean, *everything is hidden*?

Comment: @Sumithran Nothing showed ... but when move cursor, links are in the right place

Comment: maybe some styling issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of settings are misused:

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'` - this is fine

`STATIC_ROOT = '/vira_app/template'` - nope, this is supposed to be some folder not really related to the project structure. In the end, on prod it can be a CDN URL or a folder on different server. So try changing it to something like `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` for the start.

As mentioned in comments you might need to define [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) - a list of folders where **from** static files must be collected **to [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#static-root)** by `collectstatic` command. This means you can have many subfolders containing static files in different places. However you'll need to collect those files all together to deploy somewhere. `STATICFILES_DIRS` + `collectstatic` will collect all of those files for you into given `STATIC_ROOT` (and contents of *this* folder should be deployed somewhere, to CDN for example).

Note, default set of [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) already contains `AppDirectoriesFinder` which will automatically find all the `static` subfolders in any of the **project apps**. This means if you move `static` subfolder from `templates` to the `vira_app` root - you won't have to mention it in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

So:

- `STATIC_ROOT` should not point to any `templates` subfolders, change it to something more "global"
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` should link to the folder(s) where you keep your static files now or this folder should be moved to the root of `vira_app` to let `collectstatic` find it
- `collectstatic` must be run before checking your styles and scripts in rendered page
- after running `collectstatic` all the static files must persist in `STATIC_ROOT` so django will be able to map relative urls after `STATIC_URL` to relative paths after `STATIC_ROOT` and those files will be loaded

PS

Note, some of your static files are linked in wrong way in the shown template:

```
 <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
```

this should be changed to `{% static...` as well.