# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"> doesn't work

Tags: html, css, django

I link css to html on vs-code. center-aliend doesn't work here. Is there anyone who knows what part is wrong?
I want to set the text 'Hello Static!!' to the center of the browser.

<home.html>

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Static Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello Static!!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

<style.css>

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

<static_ex / settings.py>

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
```

[image: Browser output]

Comment: double check your file path for the css, make sure it's in static/css/style.css

Comment: thanks for the comment! it's in static/css/style.css as you said...

Comment: ```os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'static')``` replace your staticfiles_dirs with this. also try ```python manage.py collectstatic``` after that. 

change your html code ```<div>Hello Static!!</div>``` to ```<h1>Hello Static!!</h1>```.
your css should be ```h1 { text-align: center}```

Comment: I applied all you mentioned, still doesn't work..thanks for your comment!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you named the directory as 'css'. Change it to another name