# I can't understand how to use correct static in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to display a picture whose address is saved in the Django models attribute. As I know you need to enter in the field`url({% static  movie.img  %})` but it doesen't works.
If only use `url({% static 'img/default-movie.png' %})` it works.

That is my query sets from django shell:

```
In [21]: Movie.objects.first().img
Out[21]: <ImageFieldFile: ../MovieApp/movies/static/img/1202296.jpg>
```

P.S (I should mentioned, that these fields are in for loop `{% for movie in movies %}` )

Comment: Why are your media files in the static folder? Keep a separate folder for static and media files. I assume your settings are at least configured properly (even if media and static files are in same folder) so you want to be writing `url({{ movie.img.url }})`. As an advice have separate media and static folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Comment: if it is in media you should be able to do `<img src="{{ movie.img }}">` inside your loop

Answer (score 1):

It is not a static resource.
This should do

```
src={{movie.img.url}}
```