# How can I fix styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

i am trying to learn django and my css file cant be linked with the html file idk why

This is the tree of the static folder:

```
├── images
├── js
├── plugins
└── styles
    └── styles.css
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './styles/styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <!-- <script src="../data/script-clac.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <body class="body1">
        <div class="div1">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <p class="text">Name</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name">
            <p class="text">Username</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a username" id="username">
            <p class="text">Password</p>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Choose a password" id="password">
            <p id="result"></p>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

            <button id="btn">Calculate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error message:

> styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have been trying to fix the problem since a long time, please help me.

Also, here is my project directory

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the ./ in this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './styles/styles.css'%}">
```

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/styles.css'%}">
```

Comment: ```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Another error

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/styles.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with Django, but to me the problem looks like it's in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './styles/styles.css' %}">`. This will create a path to the css file something like `/static/./styles/styles.css`, which is why the file can't be found (hence the 404).

What you want to link to is `/static/styles/styles.css`, so the `./` at the start should be removed.

Comment: ```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/styles/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/static/styles/styles.css' %}">
```

Another error

Comment: I assume the path isn't actually ```127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/styles/styles.css```.

```<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/static/styles/styles.css' %}">``` - this line should be ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/styles.css' %}">```.

Comment: Is your BASE_DIR correctly pointing to the Registrations folder?

Answer (score 0):

add **STATICFILES_DIRS** inside setting file

ex:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```