# Django staticfiles of app does not copying in production after manage.py collectstatic

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I'm using Django + Nginx + uwsgi

Settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]

if DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/mysite/static/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
else:
    MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/mysite/media/"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

After update a code (in DEBUG = True all works good, static files are loading correct) I'm using `python manage.py collectstatic` on  `DEBUG = False` in production server and it's collect admin static, but it's not collecting static for "main" app.

In debug mode all working good.

Checked serving by Nginx - it's working correct.

Why "collectstatic" doesn't collect static from "main" app?

UPD:
I'm an idiot. Forgot about add directory with static files in git. Sry.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439076/10307728

Comment: Yes, a read all the docs about it. I'm an idiot - forgot about add directory with static files in git. Sry.