# Change Django static directory name

Tags: django, python-3.9, django-static

Django static directory name is set to `static` by default. Can it be changed to something else?. If i could change it to `cssandjs` could this bring any errors to my project? and does that also mean that in templates i would load static by `{% load cssandjs %}` instead of `{% load static %}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Comment: no it doesn't. My question was can i change the ```static``` directory name to something else so in templates it won't get presented as ```/static/css.css```. ```/static/``` comes to the path when you use the ``` {% static 'css.css' %}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the statics files con also be loded from more than one directory, this can be defined by this setting, this is where django search your files inside your server

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
    '/some_folder/cssandjs',
    ]
```

thats why you put the files inside apps folder, to avoid overlapping

the url is defined by this setting, this is what you see on the web browser

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in your template you always use {% load static %}, and django search in all your folders

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: so all django projects templates will have a ```href="/static/css/this.css``` in the place of linking the stylesheets?

Comment: will have {% load static %} at the top and {% static 'css/this.css' %}

Comment: the static url can be diferent of your static folder, you can have many static folders with diferent names

Comment: when you do ```{% static 'css/this.css' %}``` this comes out as ```/static/css/this.css``` wanted to know if i can get rid or change the name of this ```/static/```

Comment: you can, but this is related to your web server (apache, nginx, etc)

Comment: maybe you can try whitenoise, and define a folder with blank prefix http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `{% load static %}` to `{% load cssandjs %}` because cssandjs is not a registered tag library. Instead, you can change the directory name (for example `static` to `cssandjs`) and the same for `static_url='/static/'` to `'/cssandjs/'`.