# Django: template extends. Child template don't find the static image

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm learning django for a personal project. In this project i create at the first time two app "API" and "Search". Later during the develop i decide to combine search inside API and update the views of "API" with the function that was in the "Search". I create later a base template that render to two different html exstend from the base template.In the first templates (wind_index.html) all the element of the page are perfectly loaded, carousel navbar image etc. when i load in the browser the other templates (search.html), also exstend with the base.html, everything is loaded beside the images of the carousel.

Structure of the project:

```
WindPortal
API
 static
 templates
     API
         base.html
         wind_index.html
         wind_search.html
     (here where was my old APP "Search")
WindPortal
   rest of the file setting,urls
```

This is my Setting.py: i set up in APP_DIRS= False for try to don't load anymore file from the old directory but seems not working.

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'API', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'WindPortal/API/static',
    'static/img',
)
```

EDIT: base.html

```
    {% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="{% static 'API/style.css' %}">
    <title>Wind Portal</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="wind_index.html">Wind Portal</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="wind_index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wind search</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kite info</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>

<!--carousel slider -->
<div id="carouselkite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="static/img/rsz_kitesurfing1920x9083.jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="kite1">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5 class="display-4">Wind all around the World</h5>
        <p class="display-5">Wind speed and Wind Direction.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="static/img/kite3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="kite2">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5 class="display-4">Wind Search</h5>
      <p class="display-5">Use wind search for find your wind !</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Wind Search</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="static/img/kitesurfing1920x908(1).jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="kite3">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5 class="display-4">Kite school, Kitespot and more Info.</h5>
      <p class="display-5">Everything you need to know and where to be.</p>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

  </body>

</html>
```

terminal error:

```
29/Mar/2021 13:10:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3754
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:17] "GET /static/API/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:22] "GET /search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3984
Not Found: /search/static/img/rsz_kitesurfing1920x9083.jpg
Not Found: /search/static/img/kite3.jpg
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:22] "GET /search/static/img/kite3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2698
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:22] "GET /search/static/img/rsz_kitesurfing1920x9083.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2755
Not Found: /search/static/img/kitesurfing1920x908(1).jpg
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:22] "GET /search/static/img/kitesurfing1920x908(1).jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2749
```

I hope someone can explain what is wrong and the info that i post are enough. Apologize if the post looklike chaotic but is the first time that i post on Stackoverflow :).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show the template code.

Comment: i edit the file with the base.html code.

Comment: @marv8569, try this: `src="/static/img/rsz_kitesurfing1920x9083.jpg"` or `src="{% static 'rsz_kitesurfing1920x9083.jpg' %}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without leading slash this URL is relative, not absolute

```
<img src="static/img/kite3.jpg"
```

that's why in the terminal for page `search` you see URL starting with `search`:

```
[29/Mar/2021 13:10:22] "GET /search/static/img/kite3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2698
```

the absolute URL would be

```
<img src="/static/img/kite3.jpg"
```

however both are the wrong approach, for referencing static files always use `{% static %}` tag

```
<img src="{% static 'img/kite3.jpg' %}"
```

Comment: Thanks !! can i ask you to explain me why it is a wrong approach ? I'd like to learn also the why and not only the solution.

Comment: You may move static files to some other URL or folder someday and if you use template tag you'll have to update STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL settings only. Otherwise you'd have to update all the templates referencing css, images and so on.

Comment: see also this answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076

Comment: Ok if the best place for STATIC_ROOT is to select something more "global" why most of the tutorial that i saw the people place always the static root folder inside the App e not directly in the main folder of the project. In any case as you says in the post: AppDirectoriesFinder is able in any case to find the static file and will be more simple. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On dev all things are simple. On prod many websites keep their static files on different domain. Static files are more public than .py files and the folder with them must be managed differently, it's safer not to mix such files in one common folder. Tutorials are telling _how to start_, not everything.  Also Django docs have separate pages about deployment with additional notes.

Comment: If your original issue fixed please mark this answer as accepter.

Comment: Thank to very much for your help Ivan, I marked the answer as accept.