# Problem in importing the static files in the django?

Tags: python, django

I project a folder name = portfolio_projects
in which I created the app

[image]

Here is where my static folder and app is present:

[image]

code of my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_URL=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

and here is the file in which I  want to import

```
  {% load static  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "main.css" %}'>
```

here is the screenshot from the editor with marking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTQcH.png)

i am  getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZSVF.png)

Comment: for any more information please comment i will definitely reply you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That STATICFILES_URL should be STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py.

Also, clear your browser cache or in Google Chrome you can do a hard refresh by pressing Ctrl + Shift + R.

Comment: sir treid it but it was not working even I restarted the server

Comment: Also, move the static folder inside your app directory and {% load static %} at the top of the base.html

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. it woked Thanks lot. I had checked all my mistakes even i copied the and replaced some part of this from older project but i don' t that there is URL at place of DIRS