# Static files on Django 404 with static_root and static_url both set

Tags: python, django, static

I know this question has been answered a lot but I can't seem to work this out. My static files are there, at the location I've told django they are. Debug is set to True, and static_url is set to '/static/' but the static files are 404ing.

development(settings).py

```py
DEBUG = True
logger.info(f"Debug is {DEBUG}")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/phillyharper/dask/static"
logger.info(STATIC_ROOT)
```

Running `python manage.py runserver` using these settings produces this result:

```
2021-05-09 07:17:03.197 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:4 - Debug is True
2021-05-09 07:17:03.197 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:47 - Debug is True
2021-05-09 07:17:03.197 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:50 - /home/phillyharper/dask/static
2021-05-09 07:17:03.198 | INFO     | dask.settings:<module>:7 - DEV SETTINGS SETTINGS
2021-05-09 01:47:03.417 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:4 - Debug is True
2021-05-09 01:47:03.417 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:47 - Debug is True
2021-05-09 01:47:03.417 | INFO     | dask.settings.development:<module>:50 - /home/phillyharper/dask/static
2021-05-09 01:47:03.417 | INFO     | dask.settings:<module>:7 - DEV SETTINGS SETTINGS
```

However, when I click onto the page - none of the static files load. They all 404, giving this:~

```
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 22203
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1800
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/material-design-icons/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1854
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1692
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1731
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1794
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1665
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1701
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1794
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar3.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar4.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar6.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/assets/img/avatar5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[09/May/2021 01:47:51] "GET /static/src/js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1665
```

I found another thread which said use findstatic. I tried that but it shows that Django only seems to be looking inside my virtual env for static, and its not trying at the location of STATIC_ROOT. Even though findstatic doesn't find it, I can confirm the css file below does exist.

`/home/phillyharper/dask/static/src/assets/css/app.css`

```py
>> python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 src/assets/css/app.css

No matching file found for 'src/assets/css/app.css'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /home/phillyharper/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django_signally-JCl81_Vu-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /home/phillyharper/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django_signally-JCl81_Vu-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/static
```

This is my django project structure, running on WSL2.

```
.
├── certbot
│   └── conf
│       ├── accounts
│       ├── csr
│       └── keys
├── dask
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── core
│   │   ├── ethscan
│   │   ├── pricegrabber
│   │   ├── scraping
│   │   ├── trader
│   │   └── twitter
│   └── dask
│       ├── __pycache__
│       └── settings
├── nginx
│   └── user_conf.d
└── static
    └── src
        ├── assets
        ├── html
        ├── js
        └── sass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT is only used in production. In serving static during development, you need STATICFILES_DIR = ["list of directories to look through"]

There's probably some reason for this...

Comment: Docs do not say anything like this.