# Static file doesn't exist and html-file doesn't work properly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

**output:**

```
'static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
```

I've tried os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static'), but it is doesn't work. I didn't have this problem before adding new html-file and I didn't change static-folder. Setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
```

In static-folder I have placed folder 'main' and css-file. base.html

I also have a problem with the file. It doesn't work correctly. Guess I didn't wire it right.

```
<a href="{% url 'make_vision' %}"><li><button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>Добавить запись</button></li></a>
```

**make_vision.html**

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Добавление записей{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Форма по добавлению статьи</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Название статьи" class="form-control"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Анонс статьи" class="form-control"><br>
            <textarea class="form-control"><br>
            <input type="date" class="form-control"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить статью</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news_home, name='news_home'),
    path('make_vision', views.make_vision, name="make_vision"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def news_home(request):
    news = Articles.objects.order_by('-data')[:2]
    return render(request, 'news/news_home.html', {'news': news})

def make_vision(request):
    return render(request, 'news/make_vision.html')
```

When I started the server, I got an error that this path does not exist.

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:
**settings.py:**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.news_home, name='news_home'),
    path('make_vision', views.make_vision, name="make_vision"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In templates:
**make_vision.html:**

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Добавление записей{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Форма по добавлению статьи</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Название статьи" class="form-control"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Анонс статьи" class="form-control"><br>
            <textarea class="form-control"><br>
            <input type="date" class="form-control"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить статью</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```