# Python Django can't get static files to work

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

I'm working on a pyhton django project and now I'm trying to add some style to it with a styles.css file but I just can't get it to work.

My project is named commerce and my app is called auctions and I have the static file under
commerce/auctions/static/auctions/styles.css

My settings.py file include

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'auctions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My auctions/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My styles.css file

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Then in my template file, I have this

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Auctions{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'auctions/styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Auctions</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

It feels like I'm missing something obvious.

**EDIT:**
So I managed to fix my issue, and it was the STATIC_URL in my settings.py that was wrong, it looked in the wrong place. I updated it to:

```
STATIC_URL = 'auctions/static/'
```

And now it works. Thanks for your replies and help.

Comment: Hi, could you provide the Django version you are using?

Comment: Have you specified [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#static-root)?

Comment: Please show the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting too, and the `DEBUG` setting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

Addding this in your `settings.py` should solve the issue:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your settings.py file and add WhiteNoise (check [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) the lib) to the MIDDLEWARE list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s SecurityMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    # ...
]
```

You should also add this to the settings.py:

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

For more details,check [Using WhiteNoise with Django guide](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html).