# Django is not collecting all my static files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have 2 folders containing my static files (admin, and assets). 
However, when I run ***`python manage.py collectstatic`***, only the static files in the admin folder are collected.

**Below is a code snippet for static files in settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATTICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR/ "asert"
]

STATIC_ROOT = (BASE_DIR/"asert/")
```

[image]

**Below are some urls linking to the static files from an html page**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/assets.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/vendors/calendar/fullcalendar.css' %}">

<!-- TYPOGRAPHY ============================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/typography.css' %}">

<!-- SHORTCODES ============================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/shortcodes/shortcodes.css' %}">

<!-- STYLESHEETS ============================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/dashboard.css' %}">
<link class="skin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/color/color-1.css' %}">
```

Comment: You have a typo here STAT**T**ICFILES_DIRS  and take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is not defined.