# How to manage static files in Django

Tags: django

First I created a "static" folder and added a css file in this folder. Then I added `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'myStaticFiles'` in the 'settings.py'. I followed a tutorial.

I run this command: `py manage.py collectstatic`

All the files copied to 'myStaticFiles'.
Now, it's my question: Should I add more css files in the 'static' folder or 'myStaticFiles'? It's a bit confusing to me.
Django Tutorials

I followed the tutorials step by step, but didn't get the result. Explained as above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django html template can't find static css and js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files)

Answer (score 1):

You should:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'YourProjectName/static'
]
```

In `settings.py`

And the "myStaticFiles" folder should be inside your project